# Google Drive API v3 - downloading files in PHP

Tags: google-drive-api, google-api-php-client

I'm trying to understand the download flow for the Google Drive API v3 using PHP. Using the API v2 to download a file I:

- Got the file metadata
- Used the downloadUrl parameter to get a direct link to the file, attached an oAuth token to it and made a GET request to that.

Using API v3 this appears to have been deprecated, and according to the [docs](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/manage-downloads) you call `files->get()` on the Drive Service with an array parameter of `"alt" => "media"` to get the file itself rather than the metadata.

And their example was:

```
$fileId = '0BwwA4oUTeiV1UVNwOHItT0xfa2M';
$content = $driveService->files->get($fileId, array(
'alt' => 'media' ));
```

I'm having trouble understanding how this works though and have trawled through the code but it didn't give much more info.

When you call `get()`, what actually goes into `$content` in the example? Is it the contents of the file (in which case this seems troublesome when dealing with large files - surely you'll get out of memory?!) or is it some type of stream reference that I can call `fopen` on? How would I save this file to disk?

The documentation doesn't really go into any detail about what happens when you make that API call, it just says it performs a file download?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

I figured it out after a bit of experimenting.

When you call the `get()` method with the `alt=>media` parameter as specified in the docs you get the underlying HTTP response which is a [Guzzle response object](http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/latest/quickstart.html#using-responses) (as apparently the client library uses Guzzle for it's underlying transport).

From there you can call any Guzzle response method such as `$response->getStatusCode()` or you can get a stream of the actual file content.

Would have been helpful if they had documented this somewhere!

EDIT: Here's a rough example if anyone else gets stuck of how to save a file.

```
<?php

date_default_timezone_set("Europe/London");
require_once 'vendor/autoload.php';

// I'm using a service account, use whatever Google auth flow for your type of account.

putenv('GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=/path/to/service/account/key.json');
$client = new Google_Client();
$client->addScope(Google_Service_Drive::DRIVE);
$client->useApplicationDefaultCredentials();

$service = new Google_Service_Drive($client);

$fileId = "0Bxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"; // Google File ID
$content = $service->files->get($fileId, array("alt" => "media"));

// Open file handle for output.

$outHandle = fopen("/path/to/destination", "w+");

// Until we have reached the EOF, read 1024 bytes at a time and write to the output file handle.

while (!$content->getBody()->eof()) {
        fwrite($outHandle, $content->getBody()->read(1024));
}

// Close output file handle.

fclose($outHandle);
echo "Done.\n"

?>
```

Comment: Thanks, I needed that additional information but for some reason reading in 1024 blocks did not work for me. I changed the code to fwrite($outHandle, $content->getBody()) without the while and it worked.

Comment: Thanks!! Very helpful.

Comment: perfect. the loop you have here should be in the official docs for downloading large files.

Comment: could you please provide complete code what is key.json is it file which contains client id and secret key of google